# Does exists a matrix $X$ for how many $n$ such that $X^n=A$?

Tags: matrix-calculus

Let

$$
A= \begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 1 & 2 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{pmatrix}
$$

For how many $n$ is there a matrix $X$ such that $X^n=A$?

Comment: Do you know what **nilpotent** matrices / endomorphisms are?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what could be the minimal polynomial of such an $X$?

Answer (score 0):

For how many $n$? Only for finitely many $n$. More precisely only for $n\le 2$, since $X$ must be nilpotent because of $A^2=0$ and $X^n=A$. However, a nilpotent matrix $X\in M_3(K)$ satisfies $X^3=0$. It follows that $X^n=0\neq A$ for all $n\ge 3$.